# Can't create ppm File from an executable (C)

Tags: c, ide, executable, clion, ppm

I am trying to create a ppm file from inside a C program, but somehow it doesn't work.

It works fine when I am inside the IDE and run the program there. The program is executed and the file created inside the file's folder.

But once I build it and open the executable with a double click, the program runs in the terminal but does not create the file.

I am working on a mac and this is the relevant code, thanks in advance you all!

```
// from generalSettings.h

#define WIDTH 1100
#define HEIGHT 966
#define MYFILENAME "testimage.ppm"
int pictureArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH];


//from the main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "generalSettings.h"

int main()
{
    triangle firstParentTriangle;

    // these two functions "draw" sierpinsky triangles in the pictureArray
    drawFirstParentTriangle(&firstParentTriangle);
    drawChildTriangles(firstParentTriangle, numberOfRecursions);


    create_ppm();
    return 0;
}


void create_ppm()
{
    unsigned char color_black[] = "000 000 000\n";
    unsigned char color_white[] = "255 255 255\n";

    FILE *p_file = fopen(MYFILENAME, "w");
    if (NULL != p_file)
    {
        fprintf(p_file, "P3\n %d %d\n 255\n", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
                if (1 == pictureArray[i][j])
                    fprintf(p_file, color_black);
                else
                    fprintf(p_file, color_white);

        fclose(p_file);
    }
}
```

Here, I have replaced the foreground and background variables with local ones.

Generally, the program inserts 1 to the pictureArray[][] on certain elements and leaves others with a 0.

For my problem, this should be the relevant code for a reproducable example.

EDIT: Problem solver. File was created in the user folder due to missing path.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't create"? Is `NULL` returned? Does it create just an empty file?

Comment: You might want to add some output if `fopen` fails. And how do you "open" the executable? Do you double-click on some icon in your file browser? Do you run from a shell? How do you detect that the file isn't created?

Comment: What is `foregroundcolor`? The `fprintf(p_file, foregroundcolor);` is very unusual syntax. Something like `fprintf(p_file, "%s", foregroundcolor);` would be more obvious.

Comment: The executable is opened inside the console, executed and the session ends. No file is getting created. When I run the program in the IDE, it works and the file gets created.

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane, what is `foregroundcolor` and `backgroundcolor`? It's very unusual (and often bad practice) to use variables as `printf` format strings. Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part).

Comment: You haven't replied to "Does `fopen` return `NULL`?" Perhaps the file isn't created *where* you expect.  It will be placed on the "current working path", which may vary according to how you launch the program.

Comment: And talking about bad practices, it seems you use many global variables. That's also a bad practice. If you need to pass values to functions, use *arguments*.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, it was created somewhere else. I guess since I did not add a path, it was created in my user folder. Thanks!!